# Eclipse RCP: Exporting product ignores start levels and configuration properties

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-rcp

I have configured the start levels and one proeprty for my product as shown in the following image:

[image]

After export the start levels and the property in the config.ini file are different then the one I specified:

```
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
```

(Should be true, I'm aware that eclispe per default sets this property to false but I want it to be true.)

```
org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.3.100.v20100512.jar@4
```

(I clearly specified a start level of 3 AND an autostart, is this another default value?)

All the other configuration entries work. Can someone tell me why those two don't work?

Comment: Check if you are not concerned by this bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=284732

Comment: I think you forgot a link? :) Ah okay. I#m not using a custom ini file as a template. I checked "Generate a default config.ini file". It must be something different :/